# WebRTC: slow data transfer

Tags: javascript, networking, webrtc

I'm sending data between two peers in pretty much the same way as in this demo, except between peers in different tabs, not on the same page: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/datatransfer/

With two Chrome windows on the same laptop, I'm getting about a 10MB/s transfer speed - that's not very fast!

Any ideas why it is so slow and what I can do to improve it?